# AirPods not working as an input source for Voice Recorder App

Tags: ios, swift

For some reason, my voice recorder app won't use AirPods as an input source. Upon beginning a recording, the input source changes from the AirPods to the iPhone microphone. Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: What audio session category and mode have you set? Reference: https://developer.apple.com/reference/audiotoolbox/audio_session_services/1618427-audio_session_categories

Comment: Hey Eddie, was just checking in to see if you were able to sort this out. We've recently encountered the same issue but have not been able to determine what is missing either.

Answer (score 9):

There are two ways to record and play audio while AirPods are connected. For both cases we will use `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` category. The trick is to manage `AVAudioSession`s option set.

1. Add `.allowBluetoothA2DP` option. This will allow you to listen audio via AirPods and record with internal mic.
2. Add `.allowBluetooth` option. With this option you can record audio with AirPods during playback. But in this case audio quality will be reduced.

Answer (score 1):

Eddie,
If you're still having the issue, please see a similar post I made that we were able to finally resolve the issues we were having.

[AVAudioRecorder/AVAudioSession with Apple Airpods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46612223/avaudiorecorder-avaudiosession-with-apple-airpods/46695136#46695136)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i catch available output source.

```
let currentOutputSource = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputDataSource
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord, options: [.allowBluetooth, .allowBluetoothA2DP])
if let currentOutputSource = currentOutputSource {
    // Then i set known output source to input source.
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setInputDataSource(currentOutputSource)
}
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```

Answer (score -1):

It is worked for me

```
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord, options: [.allowBluetooth, .allowBluetoothA2DP]

if let headphones = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().availableInputs?.first(where: { $0.portType == .bluetoothHFP || $0.portType == .bluetoothA2DP || $0.portType == .headphones }) {
    try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setPreferredInput(headphones)
}

try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```