# RemoteIO on iOS11 with AirPods

Tags: avfoundation, ios11, avcapturesession, avaudiosession, audiounit

In iOS 10 or below, when we had an AVAudioSession set with playAndRecord category, AirPods used to be picked up as default input & output when configuring RemoteIO. I could supress output by silencing the samples in the callback but starting with iOS11, it seems AirPods do NOT get picked up as input, only output. RIO uses inbuilt mic instead and output is heard on AirPods Is this the new behavior on iOS11? If yes, how do we pick up bluetooth input such as AirPods? I also have AVCaptureSession running if that makes a difference.

Comment: What AVAudioSession options are you using?  Bluetooth only or A2DP?

Comment: Add option `.allowBluetoothA2DP` when setting up `AVAudioSession` for AirPods. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52520385/1980246

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetoothA2DP` and `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth` to `setCategory` to pick the AirPods mic by default:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                                 withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetoothA2DP
                                       error:&error]
```